# Test for independence of multivariate normality in R

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, multivariate-normal-distribution

I have 3 normal data matrices, i.e., that in each matrix, the rows are iid Multivariate Normal, but the rows of different matrices need not be identically distributed, but they have the same dimension. How can I go about testing if the 3 matrices are independent i.e., each row in a matrix is independent of any row of the other?